# How to add <select> element in Laravel jetstream / livewire code

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I'm trying to add  element to user profile form, there is no problem in the registration form  but I don't know how to add it in user profile update page

```
  <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
            <x-jet-label for="name" value="{{ __('Name') }}" />
            <x-jet-input id="name" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="state.name" autocomplete="name" />
            <x-jet-input-error for="name" class="mt-2" />
        </div>
        <!-- Email -->
        <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
            <x-jet-label for="email" value="{{ __('Email') }}" />
            <x-jet-input id="email" type="email" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="state.email" />
            <x-jet-input-error for="email" class="mt-2" />
        </div>
```

I tried to add this but it doesn't work

```
<div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
            <x-jet-label for="gender" value="{{ __('Gender') }}" />
            <select id="gender"  class="block mt-1 w-full" name="gender">


                <option value="m" {{ $this->user->gender== 'm' ? 'selected' : '' }} >
                    Male
                </option>
                <option value="f" {{ $this->user->gender== 'f' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                    Female
                </option>

            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot wire:model="gender"

Comment: Does not work is too vague. Please be more specific about the error.

Answer (score 1):

[Laravel Livewire: Input select, default option selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835137/laravel-livewire-input-select-default-option-selected)

Livewire will auto select option, just use wire:model

```
       <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
            <x-jet-label for="gender" value="{{ __('Gender') }}" />
            <select id="gender" class="block mt-1 w-full" wire:model="gender">
                <option value="m">
                    Male
                </option>
                <option value="f">
                    Female
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
```